# Grails product war build not including jQuery in views

Tags: jquery, tomcat, grails, war, production

So running grails run-app and my app runs as intended, but when I `grails war` and deploy to a tomcat instance on our staging server, jQuery does not work.

For some reason I can't jar -t the war file to view if it has the jQuery javascript library, but on the server I can see it's in the exploded view in tomcat.

And yes, I have a `<r:require module="jquery"/>` in the layout.jsp [between `<g:layoutHead>` and `<r:layoutResources>`]; as well as including this snippet on each page:

```
<g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>
```

As I said, perfect in grails run-app, not working in production :(

*edit: by not working (yes I realised that I forgot to include this in the original question), I mean that the appropriate `<script src="/static/plugins/jquery-1.6.1.1/js/jquery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" />` line is missing when viewing the exactly same page from grails run-app vs deployed war on Tomcat, and hence the page doesn't work as intended.

Comment: Working or not working with `run-war`? Also, please add more information on what "not working" means. You're getting a 404 on the file? There isn't a link to the file?

Comment: I have realised I missed the "describe why it isn't working" part of the question and have since edited it. ^^

Comment: At the same time, I can actually browse to the http://www.site.com/static/plugins/jquery/.... path and the jQuery library is there. So it's just a question of lack of <script> reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably an issue with an old version of Resources. Upgrade to 1.1.6 (the latest at this time).

Comment: 1.0.2 works, as does 1.1.6; 1.1.1 fails. Someone on IRC suggested this (and was right). Gw.